# Is there a way to integrate wordpress database with ionic app?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I already have a webpage developed on WP, with the default localhost DB. Is there a way to integrate this DB with my app? This app will be developed with IONIC 2.

If it isn't possible, can i use some external DB and access this one remotely with both applications?

Or i'll need to develop something like own CMS to have a better result?

Thanks and sorry about my english! 
Good Vibes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think You not understand what is Mobile App and what is it difference to Web App. So Mobile App is client like web browser, web browser do not connect to server database, it connects to server and server to database.

Do get data from Your Wordpress on server should be some API, for example REST API, this api on every request will query database and send results in response. So You send tipical http ajax calls from ionic app in javascript to API and get result in response.

Answer (score 0):

If it's WordPress, install and activate the [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) plug-in. It will give you some API endpoints to consume data from WordPress. Later, you can use these API endpoints to fetch data on your Ionic App.